# hash params to nice urls with routes file?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm implementing (jQuery isotope) filters for the listing index page (100 properties). The filters are price, persons, rooms, etc.

When filtering the index page...the url looks like this for example:

```
domain/en/controller
domain/en/controller#.1100
domain/en/controller#.1100.4persons
domain/en/controller#.4persons.4rooms
```

ect

This works fine. But I want nice SEO friendly urls like this:

```
domain/en/controller/4persons/2badrooms
domain/en/controller/2persons/pool
ect
```

is this possibly with the routes file and how?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that, try this in your routes file:

```
match 'controller/*persons' => 'controllers#action'
```

so, with your url:

```
domain/en/controller/4persons/2badrooms
domain/en/controller/2persons/pool
```

then you can get value of `params[:persons]`, it will have value is `"4persons/2badrooms"` or `"2persons/pool"`. You can get more info here: [Route Globbing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing).